# Converting pdf to jpg using paperclip gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rmagick

I am trying to convert pdf to images in rails . I am new to rails . I am using paperclip to upload pdf. How do I convert pdf to images and show it on browser.

I have tried the following

In model

```
has_attached_file :file_avatar, :default_url => "/files/:style/missing.doc", :styles => { :thumb => ["100x100#", :png] }
```

In controller

```
def show  
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 require 'RMagick'
 file_name=@post.file_avatar
 pdf = Magick::ImageList.new(file_name)
 thumb = pdf.scale(600, 600)
 temp = thumb.write "doc.jpg"
end
```

In view
show.html.haml

```
.image.center-block
  =image_tag temp
```

it is showing error
please help
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcHFx.png)

Answer (score 0):

First: Remove from the file_name the "`?1462460053`".

Second: Run `identify -list format` and double check that PDF is installed as a module for imagemagick. If not then you need to install it as a module delegate.